# What are the formulas to collimate an image to infinity, on a computer screen?

Tags: hud

In a Head Up Display (HUD) or WW2-era "reflector" gunsight, the image is formed at infinity, so you don't refocus your eyes between the HUD, or the sighting reticule, and the outside.

What are the formulas to simulate the same effect on a computer or a smartphone screen ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Aviation?

Answer (score 3):

This is an optical design problem.

A reflector is an optical collimator, so the light from the object to be displayed passes through a point aperture and a positive lens to turn it from a spherical into a parallel bundle of light rays. The aperture must be located at the lens focal point on its object-side

[image]

You can use both conventional ray tracing with Snell's law or Fourier optics (for this you need the transfer function of the lens and the aperture) to compute the image of the object. 
I am not aware of a closed-form solution for this problem though.

In order to simulate this effect on a computer screen you will somehow have to guess the viewing angle of the observer in front of the screen, e.g. with the acceleration sensors of the phone or by changing the view with your mouse.
There is no way to simulate this effect just by looking at a flat computer screen from a different angle.

Comment: 1- Did you mean that I need to compute the computer view with my HUD symbols set at the touch down point.  I guess I can do that, okay 
2- Is the accelerator sensor needed to account for some parallax ?